# How to get the location header in Google Apps Script

Tags: redirect, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was experimenting with building a Google Spreadsheet where:

- Column A is a list of URLs that should be 301 redirected
- Column B was our intended URL to be redirect to
- Column C is the server response code when hitting Column A
- Column D is the URL that was ultimately served up when hitting Column A
- Column E is a Boolean for B and D matching

I'm having problems with populating column D. Here is what I tried:

```
function getHeaders(tURL) {
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tURL);
   var tHeaders = response.getAllHeaders();
}
```

I was expecting that "location" would be in the response header. But it seems this method only returns a handful of server response headers. I get: X-Frame-Options, Date, P3P, Content-Length, Expires, X-XSS-Protection, Content-Encoding, Alternate-Protocol, Set-Cookie (array), Content-Type, Server, Cache-Control.

**Question**
Any suggestions on another way to get to location? Or an alternate idea on how to determine where the url was redirected to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Good tip Philip. But just so this user does not feel confused or bad, this is a **very** good question. At least compared to google-apps-script tag "standards".

Comment: Thanks @HenriqueAbreu. I'm hoping someone out there has an answer for this one. Getting to the full server response header within google sheets could help SEO folks with automating validation of redirects without having to spend money on a tool.

Comment: If you inspected the object returned on `getAllHeaders` and it's not there, well.. it's probably not possible. I guess that's why you got no answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object)) method of UrlFetchApp class and supply `followRedirects` parameter set to `false`:

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tURL, {'followRedirects':false});
```

`followRedirects` defaults to `true`, and thus your request returns the headers and content of the page it was redirected to, not the requested page. That is why you do not see the Location header there.

Comment: I had to include `headers : {connection : 'keep-alive'}` (in addition to `followRedirects : false`) in the options before this would work for me.